# Can't change back screen resolution

Tags: resolution

I used the `sudo service lightdm stop` to install a driver, (it was unsuccessfull, but it doesn't mather), then a rebooted, and since than, I'm unabel to chamnge the resolution of my laptop. I've tried so many ways, but all of them were seless.

Thanks a lot
Dani

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the "display"? it default on ubuntu, click the dash searc "display", you can change the resolution from it
[image]

Comment: There's only one option, I cannot choose the rigth one.